# Regex pattern validation js

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a regex for phone validation that should accept "space" and "+"

for example +212 0780526395

This my regex : +[0-9]\s* but it's not working

Comment: What is not working? What method do you pass the regex to? What is expected?

Comment: Try this: `/^\+\d{3} \d{10}$/`

Answer (score 0):

You were close, you have to scape the `+` if it has to be only at the beginning and let the space be between the numbers:

```
\+[0-9\s]+
```

A better aproach would be:

```
\+[0-9]+[0-9\s]*
```

To force at least one number after the + symbol.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
(.*)1?-?\.?\(?\d{3}[\-\)\.\s]?\d{3}[\-\.\s]?\d(.*)
```

Test at [Rubular](https://rubular.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Your regex, `+[0-9]\s*`:

1. `+` Matches `+`.
2. `[0-9]` Matches a *single* digit.
3. `\s*` Matches 0 or more white space characters (space, newline, tab, etc.)

So your regex matches '+8', '+8 ', '+8   ', i.e. a plus sign followed by a single digit followed by any number of white space characters.

I am assuming that the `+` character is only valid when it *precedes* all the numbers. So use:

```
^ *\+?((?: *\d){10}) *$
```

1. `^` Matches the start of the string.
2. `*` Matches 0 or more spaces.
3. `\+?` Matches an optional `+` character.
4. `((?: *\d){10})` Matches 10 occurrences (see below) of 0 or more spaces followed by a digit in Capture Group 1.
5. `*` Matches 0 or more spaces.
6. `$` Matches the end of string.

The key sub-regex in the above regex is `((?: *\d){10})`, which requires the input to contain exactly 10 digits. I just picked the number 10 arbitrarily. To allow a range of 7 to 10 digits, for example use `((?: *\d){7,10})`. Or to specify 1 or more digits are required, use `((?: *\d)+)`.

The anchors `^` and `$` are required to ensure that the input contains *only* the acceptable input.

[See Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/AQNXrK/1/)